# Geting the license codes from adobe-apps

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, cs6

I ve got an macbook from my old company i was working for and i am going to reinstall erase everything and reinstall the os. There are some adobe apps (cs6) bought for this machine. I would like to still have these apps after re-installation. So my question is how to get current serial numbers / license codes?

Comment: Contact adobe, they will sort it out for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would check out the help page on Adobe's website - [Find your serial number](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/find-your-serial-number.html).

> 1) To see a list of your registered products and their serial numbers,
>   go to the Adobe accounts page and sign in with your Adobe ID and
>   password.
>
> 2) Choose Plans & Products > View all > Products > View your products.

- From Adobe help page

It depends on how the company or you purchased the Adobe programs. If your company purchased the Adobe programs, you will have to contact them for the licensing information.